# Remove a property from a child class

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

`class c` inherits `class b` and `class b` inherits `class a`.

I need to remove a property from `c` which is part of `a`.

[tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007973/changing-the-type-of-a-inherited-property-to-a-inherited-type)

This does not support multi level inheritance.

Comment: If you want to expose only a limited subset of a class's properties and methods, you could write an interface which supports only that subset, implement that interface in C (or in all three classes), and then pass a reference to the interface type. In C#, inheritance means that `C` is guaranteed to be a superset of `A`, as far as declared members are concerned. When you pass a `C` to `Foo(A a)`, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: One should not inherit if one doesnt need it...It is better to have a completly new class, than having improper inheritance

Comment: Here in my case I wish to avoid the complex properties like list and array before I pass this to an sqlite table creation method which does not support complex properties.